# $ajax callback issue with servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

Ok, here is the problem...

I store all my "saved workouts" in the Google Datastore as Text objects.
When I view my saved workouts, the server returns all of the saved workouts in a big Array of JSON objects.  I parse these and display them by name on my JSP page.

All works fine.

Now if I want to use a saved workout again, I simply pull that workouts JSON from the Array, and use jQuery $ajax to call a servlet (which forwards to "showWorkout.jsp") to display the workout again (using the JSON passed in).

The problem seems to be that an $ajax call requires a callback.  Is this correct?

As you can see, I'm trying to forward to "showWorkout.jsp" from the servlet I passed the JSON into.  The callback seems to be preventing this.  The "showWorkout.jsp" never shows and the current page does not change.

Can I use the callback to call the "showWorkout.jsp" and include the JSON to display the workout?  I would rather NOT have the entire JSON as a query parameter in the URL.

OR... can I disable the callback and allow the servlet to forward to the JSP?

Thanks!

Comment: If the goal is to load a brand new page in the browser, you shouldn't use AJAK. You should simply post a form with the JSON set as a hidden field value. If the goal is to replace a portion of the page by the HTML fragment returned by the servlet, then you need to send an AJAX request and, using the callback function, inject the received HTML in an element of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jquery, right? So the callback is simply the function you define in the `success : function(data) {...}` The question being so worried about the callback implies to me you are doing it the oldschool way rather than actually using jquery.

If you're trying to forward back to the jsp that did the ajax call you don't get ajax at all.  That would refresh the page if it worked, and not refeshing the page is the whole point of ajax.  What you do is treat the ajax call like an asynchronous function call, and do something with the response when the callback is fired:

For instance, print the response in a message box:

```
success : function(data) { alert(data); }
```

Or, put the response into a div:

```
success : function(data) { document.getElemenyById('my_div').innerHTML = data; }
```

If you really want to have the servlet forward to a different page, or back to the same page, use a regular html form submit.

Comment: So basically if I want to forward to another JSP (e.g. showWorkout.jsp) I can't use jQuery's $.ajax call since the callback brings me back to the same page (which I don't want).

Each saved workout name shows in a HTML unordered list, so that would mean I would have to put a Form tag around each item.  Or create the form dynamically with jQuery.

The easiest thing to do I think is use "location.href" and pass the workoutID to the servlet, look it up in the DB and forward it to the display JSP.  This causes me to have to look up the workout's JSON a second time but it's not a big deal.